# How to set image on centre in FrameLayout

Tags: android

I'm doing a project in which I want to set an image in the center.I'm using TableLayout and I want set this image in FrameLayout. If u have any idea so please suggest me. Its very urgent. Thanx to all. Here is my code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

       <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:scaleType="center"
         >

        <com.nexbits.digitechi.DrawCanvas
        android:id="@+id/SurfaceView"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />


     </FrameLayout>

     <TableRow

     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="video"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_webcamera" />

    <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

         android:padding="20dip"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_twitter64" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"

         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:padding="20dip"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

         android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness64" />

      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:padding="20dip"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:src="@drawable/microscope" />
         </TableRow>
         </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 15):

Use this line in your Frame layout:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:foregroundGravity="center"

<com.nexbits.digitechi.DrawCanvas
    android:id="@+id/SurfaceView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: That line doesn't do anything in a FrameLayout.

Comment: @Patrick did you tried with android:foregroundGravity? show me your code.

Comment: @Patrick in your code you didnt put height and width for your relative layout, if your parent layout is Relative you can use layout gravity for that you need to use ndroid:layout_centerInParent="true". I dont know whats your exact problem you are facing.

Answer (score 5):

I achieved it by adding to **Child** (something inside frame layout)

```
  android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score -4):

Did you try this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
>
```

where bg is an image in the drawable-hdpi/drawable-mdpi etc.It can be bg.png/bg.jpg etc.

If you want to set the image inside the framLayout in the center,then try like the following.

```
    <com.nexbits.digitechi.DrawCanvas
         android:id="@+id/SurfaceView"

         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_vertical" or android:gravity="center_horizontal"

         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     />


 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: there is no gravity for FrameLayout